# How to create collection of scheduler task path in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script where I have to enable or disable task. In the script following thing I'm doing

1. read the $TaskPath = '\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs'
2. Get-ScheduledTask via $TaskPath
3. Get-ScheduledJob

Now in my project we have many different schedule task which is present in different path like few present at '\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs' and some task present at root path like '\printtask'.

Now when I pass the taskname to execute in the script and if that task is not present in the $TaskPath = '\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs' then it will not execute. To solve this issue I have to add another if condition for setting root path.

Lets say in the future if we have new task with some different path then I have to again add new if condition. To avoid that situation I am looking a way to have collection/list of task paths to check, Then we go through that collection/list and find the scheduled job and execute.

If in the future we need to add new task with other path, we can just add that task path to that collection/list and avoid having additional if statement.

Anyone has any suggestion how I can archive this..?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't know if I'm just tired, but I had to read this a few times to really understand what you are asking and I'm still not confident.  Are you asking how to save a list of taskpaths somewhere that you can access from the script to check if the the $taskname you are looking for exists in any of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the TaskPaths in your initial logic by building an array of objects and add all of your Task Paths in there, somewhat like this:

```
$TaskPathList = @()
$TaskPathList += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{TaskPath = $TaskPath1;}
$TaskPathList += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{TaskPath = $TaskPath2;}
```

Later on, you can iterate through this collection of TaskPaths to read them do the decision making accordingly:

```
$TaskPathList | ForEach-Object {
    if(<Place your condition to check against $_.TaskPath >)
    {
        #Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response though I'm having difficulty while getting previously I was doing like this getting path then get schedule task if task available then I will perform my actions.    $TaskPath = '\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\'
$ScheduledPSTask = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $TaskPath -TaskName $taskName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($ScheduledPSTask)
{
//here will perform my action Stop, Start, enable, disable
}  <br>   Can you please help me with how I can get Get-ScheduledTask with given your suggestion in the loop...?

Comment: You can add another property called ScheduledPSTask in every TaskPathList item once you've got the ScheduledTask for the respective TaskPath, something like `$TaskPathList += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{TaskPath = $TaskPath1; ScheduledPSTask = $ScheduledPSTask1;}` (where `$ScheduledPSTask1` is the Scheduled Task fetched from `$TaskPath1`)
Then, when you will iterate your list, you will be able to fetch your Scheduled Tasks using `$_.ScheduledPSTask`

Comment: @GauravJoshi - Did this solution/suggestion worked for you? If so, please upvote the answer and mark it as Accepted. Thanks.